# c++ defining type of a member class without template argument

Tags: c++, templates, types, member

I am trying to set the type of the member of a class, without passing it through template argument.

In details:

```
// Forward declaration:        
class A;        
class B;

class Base
{
};    

template <class T>    
class Derived : public Base
{    
    private:
        T2 var;    
};
```

where T could be either `class A` or `class B`.
What I would like to do is for `Derived<A>` T2 is int (for instance) and for `Derived<B>` T2 is double (for instance). I would like to avoid the following solution:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class Derived : public Base
{
    private:
        T2 var;
};
```

I want to avoid this because for `Derived<A>` there could be various possible combinations for T2: `Derived<A,int>`, `Derived<A,double>`, ...

What I want is that the type of T2 is unique for the entire `Derived<A>`.

Any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: why not use a concrete type, or if you really need, a typedef? You can also make a policy, which would define T2 based on your T1, such as `typedef typename Policy<T>::type T2`, i.e. http://ideone.com/FA24jO

Comment: Maybe a case for the [traits technique](http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html)?

Comment: I do not want to use a concrete type. It could differ from one run to another and I don't want to edit the class each time. However, your policiy trick is interesting. How would you use it ?

Comment: @user3127875 I think [Arne Mertz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22245532/2932052) shows the policy trick.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** The comments show that the original problem you are trying to solve is not completely explained in the question. I'll leave the original answer nevertheless at the bottom of this answer.

You cannot have two `Derived<A>` with different types T2 for the `var` member. In addition, **a variable defined by the User can not influence the type of the member variable**. Variable values are set at runtime, types are determined at compiletime.

To store a type somehow defined by the user, you will have either have to restrict the variable to a set of known types or use one type that contains a serialized version of the variable's content. The set of known types is often used in the context of databases, where the fields can have one of several predefined types (e.g. String, Integer, Boolean, Double). The type for the member variable then could be a Boost.Variant, restricted to C++ representations of that type. Another application of "user defined types" are where the user of your program has to somehow define the layout and interpretation of the type and its object, for example if your program is the interpreter of some scripting language. In that case again a Boost.Variant (or something similar) can be of use, or, since the value is probably some user provided input, just store the serialized value in a string and interpret it every time you have to deal with it.

## Original answer:

This is usually done via template metaprogramming, in this case a type function (sometimes, depending on the context, part of a traits or policy class):

```
template <class T>
struct DerivedMemVarType {
  typedef double type; //default
};

template<>
struct DerivedMemVarType<A> {
  typedef int type;
};
```

And then:

```
template <class T>    
class Derived : public Base
{  
  typedef typename DerivedMemVarType<T>::type T2;  
private:
  T2 var;    
};
```

You can also leave out the default, so that any instantiation of `Derived` for a type that you have not mapped in your function will give a compile error:

```
template <class T>
struct DerivedMemVarType; //default is not defined

template<>
struct DerivedMemVarType<A> {
  typedef int type;
};

template<>
struct DerivedMemVarType<B> {
  typedef double type;
};

//...

Derived<C> dc; // ...template error mess.... 
// --> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct DerivedMemVarType<C>'
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the problem with this approach is that in the specialization of the extra template, you fix int type to Derived<A> and double type to Devired<B>. That's not what I want. One could choose double type for Derived<A>. The way you did it, all instances of Derived<A> would have a var of type int. I would like the user to have the choice of T2 on the fly, without writing any specialization himself. Reminds me of a static variable in a class. You give it a value at the beggining and then all instances have the same values. I would like something similar but for the type T2.

Comment: @user3127875 You could have the user make the desired `T2` a special member type of `A`, `B`, etc. Then, in `Derived<Foo>`, you would say something like `using T2 = typename Foo::special_thingy; T2 var;`. Beyond that, obviously if you want them to choose the type of `T2`, they have to spell it out _somehow_. The metaprogramming method is as good as any, and you could always wrap that in a macro so the user need only say `DEF_T2(Foo, int);`.

Comment: @user3127875 then I clearly misunderstood the line that you want `T2` to be *unique* for all `Derived<A>`. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have any type specific function call, you can use something like...

```
class A;        
class B;

class Base
{
};    

template <class T>    
class Derived : public Base
{   
    public:
        Derived(T startVal):var(startVal){}
    private:
        T var;    
};

template <typename T>
Derived<T> MakeDerived(T initValue)
{
    return Derived<T>(initValue);
}
```

and now you can use it the following and the compiler should know what type you are passing to the function.

```
int initialValue = 0;
auto derived = MakeDerived(initialValue);
```

Comment: and what might T2 be? The compiler will ask you that (by throwing an error)

Comment: i use this in VisualStudio and it works without complains or problems in a 'to-any-string class'

Comment: You will have more code than this in VS. *any* compiler will complain about T2 because it cannot knwo what T2 is without prior definition. e.g. [gcc says:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47e4e1692a724d6b) "error: 'T2' does not name a type"

Comment: yup sorry my bad ... had `template <class T> ... T2 val; ...` edited and fixed that

Comment: well, now your answer has nothing to do with the question any more. The member variable should *not* have the same type as the template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a separate class that just holds a typedef which you then specialize and use in your Derived class.

```
template<typename T>
class VarType {
  public:
    typedef int TheType;
}

template <>    
class VarType<B> {    
  public:
    typedef double TheType;
};

template <typename T>    
class Derived : public Base {    
  private:
    typename VarType<T>::TheType var;    
};
```

Comment: I think it would be shorter to write directly a specialization for Derived<A> and for Derived<B>, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: As I said above, the compiler does not understand `typename VarType<T>::TheType` as a typename, but as a member. The compiler thinks TheType is a member and when it looks for it into VarType class, it does not find it.